# How to quickly switch the status bar background style when an application is started?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

This might be a bit difficult to explain in writing, so please bear with me here.

Whenever I wanted to customize the style of the status bar to the "dark" one, I simply add the following line to my AppDelegate's `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method:

```
[application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];
```

This works great, but there is a noticeable delay in changing that status bar to this dark style when the application launches. I can understand that, as the application has not completely launched yet.

However, there are a few applications out there that know a trick to make the status bar show up with the dark style instantly, right when the application launches and with no noticeable delays. One of them is Puzzlotto.

How can I do the same thing for my own application?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add a key to your info.plist to handle this:

```
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleOpaqueBlack</string>
```